# Is it bad to have an API do it's own API requests on the backend?

Tags: performance, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently working on a PHP API that would expect a lot of traffic so performance is important.
To ease work on a couple of things it would be easier to use external services. One such example would be using a hosted Elasticsearch solution or a mailing service like Mailgun.

I can't get over the idea however, that having our API calling these external API's would be bad for performance because I essentially double the amount of requests happening. (Apart from the client request to our API we add another request from our API to another API)

Am I right in thinking this is something we would want to avoid when striving to create a performant API, or would this be negligible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. If the user requests your API and your API requests another API the request time gets stretched. Simple math.

So avoid the collaboration with other APIs, if possible. If not, think about caching the external data internally so you don't have to request the external data every time.

Comment: Caching sounds like a great solution to that problem. Not very useful when it comes to search unfortunately, but I guess we'll have to work around that. Thx!